# Error running python file : ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, pycharm, pyqt5

I am trying to run Pyqt5 file on Pycharm but I keep getting this error below:

```
/Users/mustafa/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/bin/python "/Users/mustafa/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.1/scratches/scratch.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mustafa/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.1/scratches/scratch.py", line 10, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5'

Process finished with exit code 1.
```

Comment: You've to install `pyqt5` to use it. Run `pip install pyqt5` in cmd/Terminal and try again

Comment: so btw, I get Pyqt5 included in Anaconda packages.

Comment: Try this again in PyCharm Terminal or go to Interpreter settings in PyCharm to install it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think u haven't installed QT5 library yet, you need to install that from cmd.

```
pip install PyQt5
```

Comment: so btw, I get Pyqt5 included in Anaconda packages.

Comment: Can you try this one more time on your terminal? I'm using anaconda too but i had the same problem